# Speed up apply function to DataFrame with 2 million rows

Tags: python, loops, apply, rows

I want to run the Mann Kendall test on my dataframe of approximately 2 million rows.

Mann Kendall Test Function:

```py
def mk_test(x):

    alpha = 0.05
    n = len(x)
    # calculate S
    s = 0
    for k in range(n-1):
        for j in range(k+1, n):
            s += np.sign(x[j] - x[k])

    # calculate the unique data
    unique_x, tp = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
    g = len(unique_x)

    # calculate the var(s)
    if n == g:  # there is no tie
        var_s = (n*(n-1)*(2*n+5))/18
    else:  # there are some ties in data
        var_s = (n*(n-1)*(2*n+5) - np.sum(tp*(tp-1)*(2*tp+5)))/18

    if s > 0:
        z = (s - 1)/np.sqrt(var_s)
    elif s < 0:
        z = (s + 1)/np.sqrt(var_s)
    else: # s == 0:
        z = 0

    # calculate the p_value
#     p = 2*(1-norm.cdf(abs(z)))  # two tail test
    h = abs(z) > norm.ppf(1-alpha/2)

    if (z < 0) and h:
        trend = 'decreasing'
    elif (z > 0) and h:
        trend = 'increasing'
    else:
        trend = 'no trend' 
        
    return trend
```

I want to run the above function on 12 months of revenue for each customer and append the value returned by the function to the data frame.

Sample data frame (list_df):

| Customer | Revenue_1 | Revenue_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 100 | 100 |
| 5678 | 200 | 200 |

Code:

```py
list_df['MK_Trend']=list_df.apply(mk_test,axis=1)
```

Using apply takes the code more than 4-5 hours to finish.

Please suggest a faster way to achieve this.